# FULL TEXT search with normal search

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make a query that will do a full text search with 2 additional conditions. The full text part works fine. I tried these so far, and both are not working:

```js
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$query .= "WHERE MATCH(title) ";
$query .= "AGAINST('".$title."') ";
$query .= "AND state='".$state."' ";
$query .= "AND county='".$county."' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 5 ";
```

```js
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$query .= "WHERE MATCH(title) ";
$query .= "AGAINST('".$title."') ";
$query .= "MATCH(state) AGAINST('".$state."') ";
$query .= "MATCH(county) AGAINST('".$county."') ";
$query .= "LIMIT 5 ";
```

I just tried this from the comments, but I get an error 1064 near %$state%:

```js
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$query .= "WHERE MATCH(title) ";
$query .= "AGAINST('".$title."') ";
$query .= "AND state LIKE %".$state."% ";
$query .= "AND county LIKE %".$county."% ";
$query .= "LIMIT 5 ";
```

```js
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table ";
$query .= "WHERE title ";
$query .= "LIKE %".$title."% ";
$query .= "AND state LIKE %".$state."% ";
$query .= "AND county LIKE %".$county."% ";
$query .= "LIMIT 5 ";
```

Comment: county or country? If you want to search for a part of a title you can use %-signs. If the title is "stack overflow dot com" and you search for "overflow" and you want to show that row as a result you search like this:  ... `WHERE title LIKE '%overflow%'` ...

Comment: @Santy County. But what about the county and state part? The full text part works by itself, but I need to have the state and county included. Thanks

Comment: The behavior observed is described as "*not working*". It leaves us wondering whether the query is returning an unexpected resultset, or whether the statement execution is throwing an error. (We also suspect the SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL injection.)

Comment: The same with the other fields Zapp consider the %-sign as an asterisk where it means match anything at the place you're putting one. ...`WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' AND state LIKE %$state% AND `... and so on. Like spencer says, make sure your variables are escaped indeed.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think I understand. I'll try what your all suggesting. I'll make this more clear.

Comment: You don't need the match against for what you're looking for nor the opening and closing double quotes, you do need the single quotes: `$query  = "SELECT * FROM boycott WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' AND state LIKE '%$state%' AND county LIKE '%$county%' LIMIT 5 ";`